# Dynamically generate ranges for google sheet api (and/or MS Excel)

Tags: python-3.x, excel, for-loop, google-sheets

I am looking for a way to dynamically generate cell ranges in A1 notation.

To make long story short I have a python code which is to get values and cell colors from Google Sheet API.

```
ranges = ["July!C3:C105"]

def get_hours(ranges):
    service = discovery.build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)
    # The ranges to retrieve from the spreadsheet.
    include_grid_data = True
    request = service.spreadsheets().get(spreadsheetId=SPREADSHEET_ID, 
                                         ranges=ranges, 
                                         includeGridData=include_grid_data)
    response = request.execute()
    hours = []
    for item in response['sheets'][0]['data'][0]['rowData']:
        h = {}
        if 'userEnteredValue' not in item['values'][0]:
            h['amount'] = None
            h['color'] = None
        else:
            h['amount'] = item['values'][0]['userEnteredValue']['numberValue']
            h['color'] = item['values'][0]['userEnteredFormat']['backgroundColor']
            hours.append(h)

    return hours
```

But I need to do it in a loop to get everything from "C" column and so on till "AF".

So I need to add ranges somehow.

A "for" loop could be also a way to go. But I am not sure how can I add "AB, AC, AD" and so on.

Comment: Is your question about how to create with the sheets API a new column that does not exist in a standard spreadsheet (So from AA to AD)? If not, please specify?

Answer (score 0):

I am not totally sure I understand what you are trying to do. Is your issue you just need to iterate over "July!C3:AF105"? If so you could just set the range to that (but that seems like you wouldn't be asking then).

I assume then your issue is that you need separate LOGIC to handle each column? If this is the case you can still index the columns.

1. Create new sheet in the workbook called settings or dimensions or properties
2. Add a counta or a countifs that references your headers in July! this will tell you how many columns there are.
3. Map number of columns to Letters, for example in your case C appears to be index count = 1, so if columns = 2 then 1 maps to C and 2 maps to D and so on.
4. If you need row counts for those columns you can use the same countifs approach
5. In your python code get the settings table first and grab the dimensions. Then you can covert those dimensions into whatever.

   Would help to see some sample data. Or understand if you need this logic switch PER column.